# Saving images php code

Tags: php

I'm trying to save images from a url.

```
<?php
$number = 200;
while ($number <= 1000){
$url = 'http://site.com/productphotos/gallery_'.$number.'-l.jpg';
$img = ''.$number.'.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
}
$number++;
?>
```

so there is site.com/productphotos/gallery200-100-l.jpg

why isnt this working?

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the fact your URL format does not match that of the example given (as in Alex's answer), your loop will execute infinitely (`$number` vs `$num`).

Try this loop instead

```
for ($number = 200; $number <= 1000; $number++)
```

**Edit:** At least, it did before you edited the question ;-)

**Edit #2:** Syntax errors aside, I don't see PHP being the optimal solution for this "problem". You could easily write a shell / batch script using `wget` to fetch the images.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {200..1000}; do
    wget "http://example.com/gallery/${i}.jpg"
done
```

Comment: I hate it when you give an answer that is void when they edit their question. I missed it so +1 for an answer that *was* correct :P

Comment: @alex I was also typing the exact same thing as your answer when the dreaded orange bar appeared. Curse you and your similar timezone ;-)

Comment: And as Haza mentions, the $number++ is outside the while loop, so it would still go indefinitely. for loop is a much better idea.

Comment: @joe If you explain exactly how it didn't work, users can give you better answers reguarding why it may not work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you increment your $number **after** closing your while() {} function ...

Comment: Oh dear, how did I miss that? +1 for correctness and keen eye :)

Comment: @alex I don't think it was like that before the edit (when he used `$num` instead of `$number`). Hard to tell with SO's invisible quick edits

Comment: @Phil Oh, now I don't feel so bad then :)

Answer (score 2):

The string being made looks like this on each iteration...

```
http://site.com/productphotos/gallery_200-l.jpg
```

...which does not match what you quoted...

```
http://site.com/productphotos/gallery200-100-l.jpg
```

It could also be because you have `allow_url_fopen()` off. If you can't change it and it's off, use a library such as cURL to get the image.

Also, you are making 800 requests from that loop, which is quite an amount. You can give PHP a breather by using `sleep(1)` in that loop and making sure the script doesn't time out with `set_time_limit(0)`. Of course this won't be fast enough to do in a end user initiated HTTP request, so try and run this process from a scheduler such as a Cron job.

If you really want a specific answer, tell me *how* it doesn't work - any errors, is the image saved but wrong, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will do have allow_url_fopen on, so I don't know what the issue is

Comment: @Joe Have you addressed the primary issue alex mentioned; the URL format inconsistency